# Могут ли в css быть использованы одновременно width & min-width? и в каких случаях?

Tags: html, css, less, scss

Могут ли в css быть использованы одновременно одна из этих связок? и в каких случаях?

- width & min-width
- width & max-width
- height & min-height
- height & max-height

в Chrome, если прописаны противоречивые свойства - одно из свойств зачеркивается. А тут (width & min-width) нет оба не зачеркнуты. Хотя свойства min- max- не работают, а работает только width

P.S. Даже не спрашивайте причину вопроса))

Comment: да, одновременно может быть использована любая из этих связок, плюс вариант из трех свойств, например: `min-height & height & max-height` - это нормально

Comment: _А эти пары применяются почему-то нет, хотя свойства min- max- не работают_ - непонятное предложение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На практике я часто использую два значения в адаптивной верстке когда нужно задать ширину 100% (именно процентов), а максимальную ширину например 600px. Смысл в том чтобы на маленьких экранах блок был на всю ширину а на больших ограничивался 600px дабы не быть растянутым так как высота фиксированная и на больших экранах без максимальной ширины блок исказится.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я наверное именно это и хотел услышать! )) Если бывают еще случаи - буду рад узнать